# (SFDX - Package Version Creation) --- These entities are not supported: (Site)

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I'm currently trying to create a package version, but I'm encountering this error:

These entities are not supported: [Site]

The commands I used for creating a package and package version are the following:

```
# ~/Documents/Projects/public_sites

sfdx force:package:create --name public_sites --description "<desc_here>" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --targetdevhubusername ProductionOrg

sfdx force:package:version:create --package public_sites --installationkey <the_key> --wait 10 --targetdevhubusername ProductionOrg --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json
```

In the project-scratch-def.json file, I specifically added 2 features: PersonAccounts and Sites. Then in my force-app/main/default/sites I only have 1 site to deploy .site-meta.xml

​Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site is not packagable entity .You cannot package sites and hence the error .Try removing sites from the metadata folder that you package from.

**Updates**

You can see packageable metadata by going to https://yourOrgUrl/mdcoverage/report.jsp.

You can use .forceignore file to skip those that you don't want in metadata conversion

Comment: Additionally, you can see packageable metadata by going to `https://yourOrgUrl/mdcoverage/report.jsp`. I find this incredibly useful for planning my unlocked packages.

Comment: That mdcoverage report is gold. Thank you @JohnTowers . In my opinion, I think it's not intuitive to not be able to package components that can be `force:source:push/pull`-ed. But if it's a limitation, then what can I do. In addition, thanks @Mohith for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: You can use .forceignore file to skip those that you don't want in metadata conversion