# SFDX: Entities not supported on package version creation

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, unlocked-package

I'm trying to create a new package version for my SFDX project. As usual, I'm executing the following command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package MyPackage --installationkey abcdefg123456 --path force-app --definitionfile config/project-package-def.json --targetdevhubusername my-prod-org --wait 100
```

However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  These entities are not supported: [ActionFieldUpdate, WorkflowRule, ActionEmail, PathAssistant]
```

I'm using Salesforce API version 46 in my `sfdx-project.json` file and this is the CLI version information:

```
sfdx-cli/7.27.0 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.2
```

This is not the first time I create and deploy an 2G unlocked package to production but I've never seen this before.

The message is self explanatory and as per [this other post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231541/sfdx-package-version-creation-these-entities-are-not-supported-site) I know that the error can be avoided by adding the metadata to the `.forceignore` file. The real issue for me is that how is it possible that we are not allowed to package such essential features as workflow rules and actions? Does someone have any information regarding this issue? Maybe a downgrade of the SFDX CLI?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gaps can be irritating, but it is all spelled out in the Metadata Coverage Report here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47

[image: Metadata coverage for WFs]

So, you might have to live with keeping them unpackaged. Or you might not be able to adopt 2nd Generation Packaging yet.

Personally, where I've used unlocked packaging to manage big orgs, I've always had a certain amount of unpackaged metadata. Either because it's not supported, or because it doesn't fit the model (e.g. page layouts are too global).

Comment: Thanks for your comments Aidan. Can you please point me in the right direction on how to deploy from a SFDX project in other way than creating a 2g unlocked package?

Comment: You can use sfdx force:mdapi:deploy, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#cli_reference_deploy